# Why does any changes are not reflecting into word-press website?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

My client is using GoDaddy server hosting for WordPress website.If i update some changes in pages its will reflected only when dashboard is opened else changes are reflected after 4 to 5 hours.
I also contact with my service provider for cleaning cache, but its don't work.
I am not able to identity where is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This definitely sounds like a cache problem.

Depending on your website hosting plan, this can affect the changes you/other users see on the site after you've made changes to the backend. If you use a shared hosting plan, you share your website server with other websites which can slow the website and sometimes affect the cache.

Firstly, make sure you've removed cookies from your browser relating to the website in question. This can affect how the website looks until new cookies are saved from the website.

You can download a cache plugin 'W3 Total Cache' on Wordpress and this can be integrated into your website to flush the cash from the dashboard. However on a GoDaddy shared hosting plan, I've found this doesn't always work. Worth a try though!

In the same way that your web browser has a cache of recent web pages, your Internet Service Provider (ISP) may be doing some caching on your behalf.

This could be the problem, so you may have to communicate with your Internet Service Provider to fix this problem.

I would call GoDaddy customer service again beforehand and explain your problem in more detail.

Comment: Thank you for your instant reply!

Comment: I have already remove my browser cache multiple time and also added 'W3 Total Cache' for removing cache but, both doesn't work in my case senierio.I again contact with godaddy service provider.Yes, My client using shared hosting and its near by max number of files. I though its also a reason for delay in updates.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the server cache in the Godaddy? Log in to your GoDaddy account. Click Web Hosting. Next, to the hosting account, you want to use, click Manage. From the Tools section, click Website Accelerator.
Click Settings. From the Server Cache section, click Clear.

Answer (score 0):

This is `not a server issue` , this is a `cache issue`. You need to clear cache from you back end `wp-admin`. After that please check your changes with `hard refresh browser ctrl+shift+R or ctrl+f5`. Wordpress changes will be reflect on to front end.